# Adding metaData to existng pdf file

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am reading a pdf file using a path, and want to add meta data to it.

I know the adding metadata methods:

```
Documnt.addAuthor and ext...
```

But how do i get the existing pdf into a Document object?

I am reading the file like this:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfFilePath);
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(reader, out);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use: [`PdfStamper.setMoreInfo`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfStamper.html#setMoreInfo%28java.util.Map%29):

```
final HashMap<String, String> info = new HashMap<>();
if (title != null) {
    info.put("Title", title);
}
if (subject != null) {
    info.put("Subject", subject);
}
if (keywords != null) {
    info.put("Keywords", keywords);
}
if (creator != null) {
    info.put("Creator", creator);
}
if (author != null) {
    info.put("Author", author);
}

stamper.setMoreInfo(info);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
         try {
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfFile.getAbsolutePath());
                PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(pdfFile));
                final HashMap<String, String> info = new HashMap<>();
                info.put("Title", "your title");
                info.put("Subject", "your subject");
                info.put("Author", "author name");
                // ..
                stamp.setMoreInfo(info);
                // add this two lines
                stamp.flush();
                stamp.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("TAG" , "failed to add metaData " + e.getMessage());
            }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: i got crash when call stamp.close() in kotlin, 
`MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!`